# Difference between dimension and rank of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A = \left[ {\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 3 & -1 & 1 \\1 & 5 & 3\\ \end{array} } \right]$ and $V$ be the vector space of all $X\in \mathbb{R^3}$ such that $AX = 0$. Then what is $dim(V)$ ?

Here when I change the matrix into echelon form I get $\left[ {\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & -4 & -2 \\0 & 0 & 0\\ \end{array} } \right]$, which means that $rank(A) = 2$; we have one free variable and two basic variables; and $dim(null space) = 1$.

So, is the $dim(V) = rank(A) = 2$? or $dim(V)$ = number of elements in basis of null space = $1$?or we apply sylvester's law $(dim = rank + nullity)$ to get $3$??

Which will be correct and why?? Very confused... Thanks..

Comment: can you compute a basis of $V,$ the null space of $A?$

Comment: This is late, and for others stumbling upon this post. The dimension is related to rank. However the rank is the number of pivots, and for a Homogenous system the dimension is the number of free variables. There is a formula that ties rank, and dimension together. If you think about what you can do with a free variable why it is a dimension will be understood. This can get slightly more complicated but this should answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The null space is a subspace of the original vector space. Observe that the vector space in question is exactly $N(A)$, the null space of $A$.

As you observed, $rank(A) + null(A) = dim(V)$. So $2 + null(A) = 3$.

Comment: So, does that mean $dim(V)$ = number of elements in basis of null space = $1$ as they are asking about $V$ which is the null space here?

Comment: Sorry for confusing notation. I missed that you were using $V = null(A)$ when typing up my answer. I am using $rank(A) + null(A) = dim(\mathbb{R}^{3}) = 3$. You are interested in $null(A)$.

Comment: ok, got it... Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

The vector space of all $x\in\mathbb R^3$ such that $Ax = 0$ is called the *kernel* or *nullspace* of $A$.