# Calculating dimension of a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

[image]
First, I used row elementary operation on the matrix,
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
1 & -1 & 2 & 3\\
1 & -3 & 3 & 5\\
1 & 4 & 2 & 2\\
\end{pmatrix} \rightarrow
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
0 & 3 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 5 & 8\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

I had referred to [Difference between dimension and rank of matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1110140/difference-between-dimension-and-rank-of-matrix) before asking this and I am aware that $\dim(V) = \operatorname{rank}(A) + \operatorname{null}(A)$. So, I believed that the dimension of the vector space $V$ is $3 + 1 = 4$. However, I checked my answers and found out the dimension is only $3$. Could someone please explain to me why?

Comment: ``dimension" of a matrix doesn't exist, the theorem should state as $\dim(V) = \text{rank}(A) + \text{null}(A)$.

Comment: Just so that you're clear, it's not the dimension of the *matrix*, but rather the dimension of the *vector space* that the matrix acts on.  The arithmetic $3+1=4$ describes a linear map from a $4$-dimensional space to itself, whose range consists of a $3$-dimensional subspace, and the kernel (null space) is $1$-dimensional.

Comment: thanks, I did an edit @Zhanxiong

Comment: oh alright, thank you for the clarification! @SammyBlack

Comment: @Lily L The dimension of the vector space is trivially $4$. So what you asked is probably just the rank of $A$, which can be seen from the operations you made. There is no need to use any dimension theorem as you cited.

Comment: There was a statement in the question that stated "The range space T is denoted by V" and from there, I am asked to find the determinant. So, is that the rank? @Zhanxiong

Comment: @LilyL Please post the complete question. Otherwise we can only guess. The $V$ is a notation used by mine. The determinant is surely different from the rank.

Comment: I have edited it into the question @Zhanxiong

Comment: @LilyL Thank you, it's clear now. If you know that the dim of the range space is the rank of the matrix (actually it is one of the various ways to define the rank of a matrix), the problem has been solved by yourself.

Comment: Alrgiht, thanks a lot! @Zhanxiong